# PCRE Regular expression. Allow Latin, Hebrew and Greek characters

Tags: regex, pcre

Conditions:

- The string can contains a Latin character
- The string can contains a Hebrew character
- The string can contains 0, 1, 2 characters of Greek character

Examples:

- A ===> good
- b ===> good
- β ===> good
- ג ===> good
- aβ ===> good
- aaaββג ===> good
- aaaββגגג ===> good
- aβaגβaגג ===> good
- aβaaβגβגג ===> bad

In that moments I have this, but not control the Greek limit

> /^[\p{Latin}\p{Hebrew}\p{Greek}]+$/u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may a simple regex with a lookaround now allowing 3 Greek chars while allowing all others:

```
/^(?!(?:\P{Greek}*\p{Greek}){3})[\p{Latin}\p{Hebrew}\p{Greek}]+$/u
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SPy5Nn/2). You may easily customize the pattern with more conditions like that.

**Details**

- `^` - start of  a string
- `(?!(?:\P{Greek}*\p{Greek}){3})` - immediately from the start of the string, try to match 3 repetitions of zero or more non-Greek letters (`\P{Greek}*`, in the demo, it is replaced with `[^\n\p{Greek}]*` to correctly match *lines* in the multiline input) and then a Greek letter, and if the match is found, the whole regex match is failed (no match is returned)
- `[\p{Latin}\p{Hebrew}\p{Greek}]+` - 1 or more Greek, Latin or Hebrew letters
- `$` - end of string (or, better, use `\z` to match the very end of string).

Comment: Nice idea with a negative lookahead and the {3}. Once understood, this one works out pretty well

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll need it this (unreadable) way

```
^([\p{Latin}\p{Hebrew}]*)(\p{Greek}?)([\p{Latin}\p{Hebrew}]*)(\p{Greek}?)([\p{Latin}\p{Hebrew}]*)$
```

repeated groups with \1\2\1\2\1 dont work as they'd match the exact same string, not the pattern.

This regex matches your examples